# Function that fires after user's location has updated

Tags: ios, swift, callback, location, closures

**Important Note:** I am aware that I could simply call my `callback` function inside `didUpdateLocations` and achieve what I want. Unfortunately, this route cannot be taken because of some pre-existing design decisions that were made in this project (which I have no influence over).

I need to write a function that fires the first time the user's coordinates update, and then passes those coordinates to a completion handler. In my case, that completion handler is a function called `fetchCountry(fromLocation: CLLocation)` which returns the country corresponding to the `CLLocation` given.

In other words, I want to write a function similar to `didUpdateLocations`, with the capability of calling a completion handler after those updates have been received:

```
func getUserLocation(callback: @escaping (CLLocation?) -> Void) {

    // wait until user's location has been retrieved by location manager, somehow

    // prepare output for callback function and pass it as its argument
    let latitude = manager.location!.coordinate.latitude
    let longitude = manager.location!.coordinate.longitude
    let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    callback(location)
}
```

In short, `getUserLocation` is just a wrapper for `didUpdateLocations` but I am really not sure how I would go about writing this function so that it achieves what I want.

My greater goal here is to show the user a local notification **only if** they are in a certain country (e.g. United States) upon launching the app. It is a hard requirement for my application to make the decision of scheduling/not scheduling this notification inside *AppDelegate.swift*, but this decision cannot be made until the user's location has been retrieved. I plan to use `getUserLocation` inside the appDelegate like this:

I hope that I have conveyed clearly that I am looking to achieve this using a function with a **completion handler**. Here is what I would like my code to do (i.e. my use case), inside *AppDelegate.swift*:

```
// inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {

            // this is the use case of the function I am trying to write                         
            LocationManager.shared.getLocation(completion: { location in

                // fetches the country from given location using reverse geo-coding
                LocationManager.shared.fetchCountry(from: location, completion: { country in

                    if country == "United States" {                  
                        let notification = LocalNotification()
                        notificationManager.schedule(notification: notification)
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: could you just post a notification within didUpdateLocations?

Comment: Unfortunately that won't work. The bigger picture, which I left out of the question in order to keep the scope reasonable, is that I want to schedule a local notification to trigger ONLY after the user's country has been determined (I have a function called `fetchCountry(fromLocation: CLLocation, completion: @escaping (_ country:  String) -> ())` which I would call as the `callback` and then only schedule the notification after I have the user's country). Posting a notification within `didUpdateLocations`, won't help I believe

Comment: I "think" there is a way to determine when a certain location accuracy has been reached with the native api. Once the accuracy is accurate to lets say 100m, fire up the callback. And by then should be able to determine the country.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit @arvidurs?

Comment: have a look at this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423836-desiredaccuracy
you can check if a certain accuracy has been reached. Once it has, you know its accurate enough to call the fetch country

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edited the whole answer. You would need to use a synchronizing api (`OperationQueue`, `DispatchQueue`, etc) because your `CLLocationManager` is already fetching even before `getUserLocation` is called. Callbacks alone can't handle this that's why I removed that option already. For this case, I used `DispatchQueue` because I prefer using it, to each their own.

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    static let shared: LocationManager()
    private let privateQueue = DispatchQueue.init("somePrivateQueue")
    private var latestLocation: CLLocation!{
        didSet{
            privateQueue.resume()
        }
    }

    func getUserLocation(queue: DispatchQueue, callback: @escaping (CLLocation?) -> Void) {
        if latestLocation == nil{
            privateQueue.suspend() //pause queue. wait until got a location
        }

        privateQueue.async{ //enqueue work. should run when latestLocation != nil

            queue.async{ //use a defined queue. most likely mainQueue

              callback(self.latestLocation)
              //optionally clear self.latestLocation to ensure next call to this method will wait for new user location. But if you are okay with a cached userLocation, then no need to clear.
            }
        }

    }

    func fetchCountry(from currentLocation: CLLocation, completion: ) //you already have this right?

    @objc func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
           didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]){
         latestLocation = locations.last! //API states that it is guaranteed to always have a value
    }

}
```

I also agree on using a 3rd party library if possible. Those code would be guaranteed to be unit-tested and handle edge cases. Whereas, my above code could have a bug (none that I know of btw)

Comment: Hey @Joshua Francis Roman thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I appreciate that you went through the question carefully and devised an answer to fit my specific requirements. I am in the process of reviewing what you wrote and see if it solves it.

Comment: A couple of updates: It looks like the queue method will not work because `didUpdateLocations` won't have been called yet when I am actually calling `getUserLocation` in AppDelegate (and thus I am unwrapping `location` to a nil). The first method isn't working either right now, although I suspect it might be because of some details I still have to fine-tune

Comment: I figured out what was wrong with the first approach! Unfortunately, there is a sneaky race condition that happens in `didUpdateLocation`. Right where you are checking if `getLocationCallback` is nil. The race condition happens because `getUserLocation` some times does not assign `self.getLocationCallback = callback` fast enough before `didUpdateLocations` has reached the nil check. Not sure how to work around this problem

Comment: Hi, I assume the location is already searching before getUserLocation is called right?

Comment: Also, "It looks like the queue method will not work because didUpdateLocations won't have been called yet when I am actually calling getUserLocation".Hmm, that is weird. The  purpose of the queue is to ensure that your callback inside `getUserLocation` won't be called until `didUpdateLocations` has fired. Don't understand why it passed nil. Updated the answer though to use a cached userLocation and handle the race issues I've noticed

Comment: I ended up fixing the issue using a cached value that was provided in the project. However, your updated answer looks very legitimate and you have helped me think of different viable ways to solve this problem. I am sure it will help many other developers in similar situations as me. A bounty well deserved!

Answer (score 1):

From your AppDelegate code I can assume that you are determining the country in the LocationManager class only. I would suggest to remove the call back from the getUserLocation() function and create a different function named postLocalNotification() in the AppDelegate to just post the local notification.

When you start fetching the user location the didUpdateLocation will be called in which you should call the fetchCountry() with the latest location. If the fetched country is proper and you want to post the local notification get the appelegate object and call the function which will post the notification as below

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.postLocalNotification()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I am specifically looking to achieve this using a callback function!

Comment: Hi, I posted an answer. I hope it fits your design requirements

Comment: Although I awarded the bounty to another answer, I still appreciate you sharing your knowledge. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use [PromiseKit+CoreLocation](https://github.com/PromiseKit/CoreLocation)?

It provides `CLLocationManager.requestLocation(authorizationType:satisfying:)`. If you don't want to import all the [PromiseKit framework](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) (which is great & avoid such completion chain), you can copy [its code](https://github.com/PromiseKit/CoreLocation/blob/f3f3d8525e9ea9fbc19ac269c80413a5454e9a8e/Sources/CLLocationManager%2BPromise.swift). They did exactly what you want: wrapping the `CoreLocation` request in a function.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Being a new construct introduced in Swift5, promises are not compatible with Swift 3/4. As specified in my post, I am looking for an answer that specifically uses a completion handler chain

Comment: Promise 6.0 is compatible with Swift 4. And, as I said, you can use almost the same code. Make CoreLocation compatible with PromiseKit is the same as make CoreLocation compatible with your completion handler pattern.

Comment: Although I awarded the bounty to another answer, I still appreciate you sharing your knowledge. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your special requirements are so this is general advice.

It sounds like you should set up a second location manager for your own use. Set it up in the app delegate and put its delegate callbacks in there, separate from the main location manager.

Don't try to delay `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from finishing. Depending on your requirements you might have to move any UI setup code to your own callback to set up the interface after the country is determined. I would even consider showing a different UI while you're doing this location and notification set up, then swap it out for the main UI when your have notification permission, location permission and the country.

Realise that the first location update you get through `didUpdateLocations` can be inaccurate. Check its distance accuracy but also check its `timestamp` and discard any update that's old. For your purposes (country accuracy) that probably means older than an hour. You're only really considering the use case where your app was opened for the first time after a user gets off a plane coming from another country. For accuracy, if the timestamp is recent, anything under 3000m or 5000m will be fine for that level.

Because the required accuracy is so low the location will be coming from cell tower triangulation. It should be fast (maybe within 2-5 seconds).

The one thing I'd be careful about is that your location manager will have to request location permissions while the main location manager does the same thing. I don't know how requesting permissions twice like that works.

I'd also separate fetching the country and getting location from the notification permissions.

Some more general advice: Your use case looks like it's handled in the WWDC session for [Advanced NSOperations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/226/). The speaker handles cases where you need several things to be set up before the next part can move on. There's a location use case and a permissions use case in there too, one depending on the other.

Comment: Hey @nevan king. Thanks for your insightful answer. I am taking your advice into account and seeing how that would change my architecture. I will get back to you.

Comment: Although I awarded the bounty to another answer, I still appreciate you sharing your knowledge. Upvoted.